# InDesign script to insert pages between existing ones

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript, script

I try to create a very simple script that adds one page after every existing page of the document and applies one of the masters to it.

Unfortunately I have a problem with referencing objects in Extend Script.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var numOfPages = docRef.pages.count();

for (currentPageNumber = 1; currentPageNumber <= numOfPages; currentPageNumber += 2) {
    var pageRef = docRef.pages.item[currentPageNumber];
    pageRef = docRef.pages.add(LocationOptions.AFTER, pageRef);
    docRef.pages[currentPageNumber + 1].appliedMaster = docRef.pages.masterSpreads.item ('T-test');
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand where I've missed something to get this running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your script. First, as you mentioned, the referencing is not quite correct.

The item property of a collection is not an array, so you cannot address it as such. Instead you can use the pages collection itself like an array. So your line

```
var pageRef = docRef.pages.item[currentPageNumber];
```

should be changed to

```
var pageRef = docRef.pages[currentPageNumber];
```

Note that this collection is zero-based, so your loop should start at zero.

Also, `masterSpreads` is not a property of `pages`, but of the doc itself, so the last line needs to be changed to

```
docRef.pages[currentPageNumber + 1].appliedMaster = docRef.masterSpreads.item ('T-test');
```

Lastly, your loop as it is now will mess up the page indices, as you keep adding new pages. Let's say your document has 8 pages in the beginning, then you would need to end up with 16 pages in the end. However, the loop ends after it reachers `numOfPages` (8) and thus will only add half the pages. You therefore have to loop backwards and start adding a page behind the last page, then one behind the page before that and so on. So your loop will have to look like this:

```
for (var i = numOfPages - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  $.writeln("i: " + i);
  var pageRef = docRef.pages[i];
  pageRef = docRef.pages.add(LocationOptions.AFTER, pageRef);
  docRef.pages[i + 1].appliedMaster = docRef.masterSpreads.item('T-Test');
}
```

This way it should work.

Comment: Indeed, now it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. I should invest more time in investigating the reference...